# How quickly does $(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$ converge to $e$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

The definition of $e$ boils down to the existence of a limit:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n = 2.71828... $$

And we give this constant a special name, "$e$".  This limit arises naturally if you want to take the [derivative of $a^x$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29#e_in_calculus):

$$ \frac{a^{x+\epsilon} - a^x }{\epsilon} = a^x \frac{a^\epsilon - 1}{\epsilon} $$

I would like to know the **next-order** term or factor here.

Maybe I can use the Taylor series of $\log (1+x) = x + x^2/2 + O(x^2) $ to get a bound?

$$ n \log \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right) = n \left( \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{n^2} + \dots \right)$$

---

The specific example I have in mind, comes from examining the derivation of the [Demoivre-Laplace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem) limit formula:

$$ \binom{n}{k} p^k q^{n-k} \simeq \frac{1}{2\pi n pq} e^{-\frac{(k-np)^2}{2npq}}$$

However, I am not using their derivation.  If interested, I am trying to find the $n \to \infty$ asymptotics of

$$ p^nq^n \left[ p^{t\sqrt{n}}q^{-t\sqrt{n}} \binom{n}{pn + t \sqrt{n}} -  p^{-t\sqrt{n}}q^{t\sqrt{n}}\binom{n}{pn  - t \sqrt{n}} \right]$$

You can answer here, or I can ask in a separate place.

Comment: Yes, Taylor expansion of $\log (1+x)$ gives the first few largest terms in the difference $e - \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ without much ado.

Comment: Your last displayed expression equals zero by the way.

Answer (score 4):

Taylor series is one way to go.  Check your formula for $\log(1+x)$ again though, it should be $x - x^2/2 + O(x^3)$.  Then

$$
\exp\left(1 - \frac{1}{2n} + \cdots\right) = e \cdot \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2n} + \cdots\right) = e \cdot \left(1 - \frac{1}{2n} + \cdots\right).
$$